# Why does this script give error?

Tags: shell-script, kali-linux

Why does this script give error?

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script checks whether 
# the current user is root or 
# not.
if [ $UID -ne 0 ] then
    echo "Non-root user."
else
    echo "Root user."
Fi
```

---

### Output

```
myuser@kali:~$ ./user.sh
./user.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
./user.sh: line 7: `else'
myuser@kali:~$
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have forgot to put `;` between `if` and `then`:

```
if [ "$UID" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Non-root user."
else
    echo "Root user."
fi
```

Also the `if` conditional construct ends with `fi`, not `Fi`.

`;` is basically a shorthand for newline. If you want you can use `then` in the next line to avoid `;`:

```
if [ "$UID" -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "Non-root user."
else
    echo "Root user."
fi
```

Comment: let me see again.

Comment: Alternatively you may put the `then` keyword on a seperate line (the line below `if`) to avoid the need of the semicolon `;`.